# Django dynamic form field display

Tags: python, html, django, forms

How can I render a django form field on my html page only when a certain boolean field is selected.

forms.py:

```
....
choose_encryption = forms.BooleanField(label='Would you like encryption?')
key1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
key2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
...
```

new_file.html:

```
....
<p> {{ form.choose_encryption }} </p>
when form.boolean_field becomes true: 
    <p> {{ form.key1 }} </p>
    <p> {{ form.key2 }} </p>
....
```

is there a widget/attr for this that makes it possible without reloading the page or calling a view?

thanks

Comment: You could do it with jQuery...Load all the fields by default, but hide the "encryption" ones unless the box is checked.

Comment: There is a jQuery lib I made for this purpose: https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies